Getting error while set up the SD card for Duckiebot
I am facing trouble while setting up the SD card. I am explaining everything so that I can get a solution.
I am using Duckiebot DB21J and NVDIA JETSON NANO.
Operating system is Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.

At first, I take the SD card and adapter which comes with Duckiebot. I started the procedure according to the manual. But the downloading was stuck, so I closed the terminal and formatted the SD card. I am trying to do this from Germany.

Now, when I try again to set the SD card with the same method according to the Manual, I get an error in my terminal the error message is,
 Archive:  /tmp/duckietown/dts/init_sd_card/dt-nvidia-jetpack-v1.3.0-4gb.zip
   End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
   a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
   latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
   the last disk(s) of this archive.
 unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /tmp/duckietown/dts/init_sd_card/dt-nvidia-jetpack-v1.3.0-4gb.zip or
         /tmp/duckietown/dts/init_sd_card/dt-nvidia-jetpack-v1.3.0-4gb.zip.zip, and cannot find /tmp/duckietown/dts/init_sd_card/dt-nvidia-jetpack-v1.3.0-4gb.zip.ZIP, period.dts :  Traceback (most recent call last):
     :    File "/home/ferdous/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dt_shell/environments.py", line 43, in execute
     :      shell.onecmd(cmdline)
     :    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/cmd.py", line 217, in onecmd
     :      return func(arg)
     :    File "/home/ferdous/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dt_shell/shell.py", line 729, in <lambda>
     :      do_command_lam = lambda s, w: do_command(s, w)
     :    File "/home/ferdous/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dt_shell/commands/commands.py", line 136, in do_command
     :      return descriptor.command.command(shell, args)
     :    File "/home/ferdous/.duckietown/shell/profiles/daffy/commands/duckietown/init_sd_card/command.py", line 349, in command
     :      data.update(step2function[step_name](shell, parsed, data))
     :    File "/home/ferdous/.duckietown/shell/profiles/daffy/commands/duckietown/init_sd_card/command.py", line 440, in step_download
     :      _run_cmd(["unzip", data["disk_zip"], "-d", parsed.workdir])
     :    File "/home/ferdous/.duckietown/shell/profiles/daffy/commands/duckietown/init_sd_card/command.py", line 829, in _run_cmd
     :      subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=shell, env=env, **outputs)
     :    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
     :      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
     :  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['unzip', '/tmp/duckietown/dts/init_sd_card/dt-nvidia-jetpack-v1.3.0-4gb.zip', '-d', '/tmp/duckietown/dts/init_sd_card']' returned non-zero exit status 9.
     :  dts :  To report a bug, please also include the contents of /home/ferdous/shell-debug-info.txt



At this moment, what should I do?
How can I solve this error?
I am looking for a solution.
